# Best way to test dependencies of my .deb package?

Tags: dependencies, deb

I have a project that builds an application, which I want to release as a `.deb` package, initially uploaded to a website, and perhaps later on a PPA.

I'm not interested in adding it to any Linux distro, or even providing a source package.

I know there are lots of tools for building debs, but they make a lot of assumptions about workflow that I don't want to deal with. Instead, I've done pretty well so far with `dpkg-deb`, and then fixing any issues found by `lintian`. But it's not clear to me the best way to be sure that the list of package dependencies (`Depends:` line in the `control` file) is correct.

My current approach is to build a chroot box with `debootstrap --variant=minbase stable`, install my package in it, and then run my app to see what breaks. Is this sensible or is there a better way?

Comment: My new approach is to install and run it in a Docker container, using the image `bitnami/minideb:latest`.

Comment: Run `$ dpkg-shlibdeps -t [executable]` ... Conditions : A directory "debian/" with an empty file "control"  ...  And the file `debian/substvars`  will be created : substvars is a text file. ... I.e. `Folder/{executable, debian/control}`